# $0\in \mathbb{R}$ is not a regular value of g(f)

Tags: analysis, smooth-manifolds

This question is from my assignment on submanifolds and I was unable to solve it.

> Let $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x,y,z)=(x^3,y)$ and $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be given by g(x,y)=y. Show that $(1,0)\in \mathbb{R}^2$  is a regular value of f and $g(1,0)=0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is a regular value of g, but $0\in \mathbb{R}$ is not a regular value of the map $g(f(x))$.

Kindly tell the latex code of composition of two functions , I googled a lot but couldn't find it.

I have proved it that the first two maps are regular, but I was unable to do the third map. g(f(x)) is a map from $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that g(x,y,z)=y ,$\nabla g(f)(x)$=1 which has rank equal to that of $\mathbb{R}$ for all (x,y,z) so I think it should be a regular value of the given map.

So, what mistake I am making?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your gradient is not correct, but otherwise, I think you right. $0$ is indeed a regular value. You know that $g(f(x,y,z)) = y$. The gradient is $\nabla (g \circ f)(x,y,z) = (0, 1, 0)$, which has rank 1. In particular, for any $u \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that $\langle  \nabla (g \circ f)(x,y,z), (0,u,0)\rangle = u$, showing that the derivative is surjective at each point.

PS: The LaTex code for composition is \circ

Comment: How do you wrote that $\langle  \nabla (g \circ f)(x,y,z), (0,u,0)\rangle$ equals u? Can you please explain in detail?

Comment: This is the dot product of the gradient with $(0,u,0)$. The gradient being $(0,1,0)$, this dot product equals $0 + 1 \cdot u + 0 = u$.